# Skyscanner Widget on SSL page not working

Tags: https, skyscanner

I try to use the skyscanner Widget on an SSL page. SSL is provided by cloudflare.

Now I am getting the "Loading insecure resource on secure page error" and the Widget is not loaded.

See https://www.addismap.com/
vs. http://www.addismap.com/

I am Loading the Widget already via HTTPS but it tries to load parts via HTTP. Probably a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has been updated to include instructions of how to host the Widget in a page using SSL.

http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/WidgetsStart

Specifically, include the `ssl=true` GET parameter in the `<script>` tag.

Disclaimer: I'm a Skyscanner employee.

Comment: I see : "var skyscanner = window.Skyscanner;skyscanner.loader.ApiServer = 'http://api.skyscanner.net';skyscanner." from https://api.skyscanner.net/api.ashx?key=3a55e635-ab67-4aee-9eb8-8aa96a83d70f : is seam it's a Skyscanner bug

Comment: Yes Tom, I can recreate this bug. Alex - contact us here http://ww2.business.skyscanner.net/contact-us/ and we can inform you when this is fixed.

Comment: @lain: Contacted you a while ago via the contact-us page. No response. StackExchange seems to be the only way to get through. Still not fixed? Any estimate? Should not be that hard to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the widget over HTTPS.

[Blocked by browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTaNs.png)

Comment: I did via a //example.com link and the initial part is loaded via HTTPS